# Plasma Treatment of LaAlO3: Surface Roughening

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics

I'm trying to understand something I've observed in exposing LaAlO3 substrates to an oxygen plasma (yielding atomic oxygen).  In literature, these substrates are frequently "cleaned" in a oxygen rich environment by exposing the surface to atomic oxygen (via plasma source) at substrate temperatures greater than 700 C.  This typically results in a clear diffraction pattern indicative of a flat surface.  In my experiments, I'm noticing that initially, the surface improves upon plasma exposure (enhanced diffraction intensity), but after a certain point, the intensity of the diffraction pattern begins to fade, and (presumably) the surface becomes disordered.

I'm looking for insight into why this might be happening, because typically the surface will be exposed to the atomic oxygen plasma during growth, but this seems to be damaging my film.  My first guess would be that initially, atomic oxygen reacts with surface species to produce a clean surface, and, after a point, begins to somehow erode the surface, reducing crystallinity.

Answer (score 0):

The oxygen rich condition will normally lead to a change in stoichiometry up to a certain degree. Thus, you will expect to have interstitial oxygen atoms possibly compensated by cation vacancies.